# Cut hole without stroke into object with stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I have a custom white object with black stroke, like this:

[image]

I want to cut a hole into that, so I create an object like this:

[image]

If I do `Minus Front` from the pathfinder, I get this:

[image]

But I don't want the stroke on the circle in the middle. How can I do that?

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: The prototype is not a compound shape you want to create - it cannot have external stroke without internal one.

Comment: @Ilan: But how can I do a shape like the one below then?

Comment: It is the easiest task in the world :) it is just a circles above the shape with black stroke. Think layers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative to @Ilan's method would be to add a secondary shape for the black outline. This way you can alter the color boxes and there *are* holes in the top shape so you don't have to alter the color for multiple objects.

Just copy the outer shape and `Edit > paste in Front` then apply a black stroke and no fill. You can then `Group` it with the white shape to move them as one object.

[image: ![enter image description here]

In any event, if you don't want strokes on the inner circles/holes you'll need at least one other object.

Comment: Where this nice gradient came from? %))

Comment: ... artistic license @Ilan :) Just needed to show the construction basics, and not adhere perfectly to the sample image. :)

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: I added the gradient (black to white set to overlay mode at 50% opacity). The *actual* color fills are inconsequential to the question.

Comment: No. [I rebuilt the image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/osImU.jpg). It was much quicker, and more accurate, just to recreate it than it would be to trace it.

Comment: sorry I deleted the question about trace unintentionally.  I think your answer should work better. +1

Answer (score 1):

As I commented you cannot make a hole in a way you try (because of a stroke).

But actually, this picture does not imply any compound shape - there are just regular ones layered one upon another:

I did it in a minute:

[image]

These are the layers:

[image]

(made on the retina, thus the size was doubled - sorry about that)

Comment: The circles inside the shape belong to the paths, they are not seperate objects.

Comment: How do you know %)

Comment: It's my object. :-D

Comment: Anyway  the issue is the stroke....